# SSH: no port[s] to connect to

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel, ssh-keys

I can connect to machine `m2` by logging in to `m1` first:

```
[laptop]$ ssh ubuntu@m1.com
[m1]$ ssh ubuntu@m2.com
[m2]$ # i'm in!
```

Both machines use SSH key to log in (not passwords), and it works.

But when I try to automate this with SSH proxying, by using the following config:

```
Host m1
  ForwardAgent yes
  User ubuntu
  HostName m1.com

Host m2
  ForwardAgent yes
  User ubuntu
  ProxyCommand ssh -q m1 nc m2.com
```

it fails with:

```
[laptop]$ ssh m1
[m1]$ # ok, works

[laptop]$ ssh m2
no port[s] to connect to
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

Why can I connect manually to `m2.com`, but not in two hops via config?
How to fix it?

Comment: ProxyCommand ssh -q m1 nc m2.com 22

Comment: Oh yes, my stupidity. Please submit as answer so I can accept @FlorinAsăvoaie.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to specify the port.

```
  ProxyCommand ssh -q m1 nc m2.com 22
```